# iOS navigation change to back button, align right

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a requirement for the user interface to have the back button, and its behavior, right aligned instead of left aligned.

it would look something like this

http://content.screencast.com/users/Quotient/folders/Jing/media/a325c184-5b34-40c3-b1bc-104d3d022eb2/2013-01-10_0643.png

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: the Apple probably won't allow this solution, read the `HIG` *(Human Interface Guideline)*. this solution could cause of high risk of the rejection of the application, because it is against the standard iOS interface layout of system control elements.

Answer (score 0):

In this [post](http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=401) you will find how to create a custom back button, all you has to do is place it in the right side instead of the left one